# Stack in Java and object cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, arrays, stack

How can I reference to this piece of code?

```
    class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        Person thePerson1 = new Person("Name1", "Surname1", 1901);
        Person thePerson2 = new Person("Name2", "Surname2", 1901);
        Person thePerson3 = new Person("Name3", "Surname3", 1901);
        Person thePerson4 = new Person("Name4", "Surname4", 1901);
        Person thePerson5 = new Person("Name5", "Surname5", 1901);

        Stack<String> thestack = new Stack<String>();
        thestack.push(thePerson1);
        thestack.push(thePerson2);
        thestack.push(thePerson3);
    }
}
```

I have an issue: 
incompatible types: Person cannot be converted to java. lang. String, line 56
Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags: verbose to get full output, line -1

How to change the type of the Stack If I want to use thePerson1, thePerson2,etc?

Comment: `Stack<Person> thestack = new Stack<Person>();`

Comment: Or `thestack.push(thePerson1.toString());` depending on what you’re trying to do, but my guess is you should change the stack type.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it as a `Stack<Person>`, not a `Stack<String>`:

```
Stack<Person> thestack = new Stack<Person>();
```